# velodyne HDL -64E S2 launch file configuration

Tags: ros, velodyne-pointcloud, ros-kinetic, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello All,

I am currently working with velodyne HDL -64E S2 model of LiDAR and am trying to get data using ROS package with modifying to the launch file configuration.

```
 <launch>
    <!-- pointcloud cloud_nodelet -->
      <arg name="velodyne_calibration" default="$(find velodyne_pointcloud)/params/hdl64e_s2_calib.yaml" />
      <!-- <arg name="velodyne_calibration" default="" /> -->
      <arg name="min_range" default="2.0" />
      <arg name="max_range" default="65.0" />
      <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="cloud_nodelet"
            args="load velodyne_pointcloud/CloudNodelet velodyne_nodelet_manager">
        <param name="calibration" value="$(arg velodyne_calibration)"/>
        <param name="min_range" value="$(arg min_range)"/>
    <param name="max_range" value="$(arg max_range)"/>
  </node>

  <!-- start nodelet manager and load driver nodelet -->
  <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="velodyne_nodelet_manager"
        args="manager" />
  <arg name="model" default="64E_S2" />
  <arg name="pcap" default="" />
  <arg name="read_once" default="true" />
  <arg name="read_fast" default="true" />
  <arg name="repeat_delay" default="0.0" />
      <!-- rotating parameter -->
      <!-- 1) if your setting rpm is 1200(20Hz) -->
      <!-- <arg name="rpm" default="850.0" /> -->
      <!-- 2) if your setting rpm is 900(15Hz) -->
      <!-- <arg name="rpm" default="850.0" /> -->
  <!-- 3) if your setting rpm is 600(10Hz) -->

  <arg name="rpm" default="570.0" />

  <!-- 4) if your setting rpm is 300(5Hz) -->
  <!-- <arg name="rpm" default="290.0" /> -->

  <arg name="frame_id" default="velodyne" />

      <node pkg="nodelet" type="nodelet" name="driver_nodelet"
            args="load velodyne_driver/DriverNodelet velodyne_nodelet_manager" >
        <param name="model" value="$(arg model)"/>
        <param name="pcap" value="$(arg pcap)"/>
        <param name="read_once" value="$(arg read_once)"/>
        <param name="read_fast" value="$(arg read_fast)"/>
        <param name="repeat_delay" value="$(arg repeat_delay)"/>
        <param name="rpm" value="$(arg rpm)"/>
        <param name="frame_id" value="$(arg frame_id)"/>
      </node>
</launch>
```

//===========================================================================================
Calibration file : hdl64e_s2_calib.yaml

```
lasers:
- {dist_correction: 0.981637605, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: 0.025999999, laser_id: 0, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: -0.09709912400667693, vert_correction: -0.12678532453409336,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.19740748}
- {dist_correction: 1.2924338, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: -0.025999999, laser_id: 1, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: -0.06057167088908498, vert_correction: -0.12094779159811801,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.19783373}
- {dist_correction: 1.270309331, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: 0.025999999, laser_id: 2, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: 0.0384232803656565, vert_correction: 0.003765600221055326,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.20684389}
- {dist_correction: 1.2513616650000001, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0,
  focal_distance: 0, focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: -0.025999999, laser_id: 3,
  max_intensity: 255, min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: 0.07774204553728, vert_correction: 0.008671371682560988,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.20719664999999998}
- {dist_correction: 1.0604789110000001, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0,
  focal_distance: 0, focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: 0.025999999, laser_id: 4,
  max_intensity: 255, min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: -0.02274002397859877, vert_correction: -0.11631209238506594,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.1981718}
- {dist_correction: 1.3109244240000002, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0,
  focal_distance: 0, focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: -0.025999999, laser_id: 5,
  max_intensity: 255, min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: 0.01614102308860006, vert_correction: -0.10965216030555087,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.19865684000000003}
- {dist_correction: 1.084458345, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: 0.025999999, laser_id: 6, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: -0.03625398445841397, vert_correction: -0.1508442868471072,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.19564366}
- {dist_correction: 1.3612504920000001, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0,
  focal_distance: 0, focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: -0.025999999, laser_id: 7,
  max_intensity: 255, min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: 0.003226443580504749, vert_correction: -0.14504506388821317,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.19606992}
- {dist_correction: 0.9976554000000001, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0,
  focal_distance: 0, focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: 0.025999999, laser_id: 8,
  max_intensity: 255, min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: 0.05223313349487931, vert_correction: -0.10399361088436754,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.1990684}
- {dist_correction: 1.324527304, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: -0.025999999, laser_id: 9, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: 0.09040955798179223, vert_correction: -0.09772098481916251,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.19952404999999998}
- {dist_correction: 1.085785638, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,



focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: 0.025999999, laser_id: 10, max_intensity: 255,

  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: 0.03886123583485944, vert_correction: -0.13943648324351443,[C:\fakepath\velo64ES2.png](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/15338846705941777.png)
  vert_offset_correction: 0.19648147000000002}
- {dist_correction: 1.382572669, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: -0.025999999, laser_id: 11, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: 0.07747097146983575, vert_correction: -0.13321667084147476,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.19693712000000002}
- {dist_correction: 1.015353365, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: 0.025999999, laser_id: 12, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: -0.0972409529523525, vert_correction: -0.05586549353550814,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.20255193999999999}
- {dist_correction: 1.364271173, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: -0.025999999, laser_id: 13, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: -0.058071130688435696, vert_correction: -0.050157935268928804,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.20296349}
- {dist_correction: 1.200094107, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: 0.025999999, laser_id: 14, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: -0.11071594721128768, vert_correction: -0.09123794185933705,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.19999440000000002}
- {dist_correction: 1.360941574, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: -0.025999999, laser_id: 15, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: -0.07145930005307191, vert_correction: -0.08576184915815721,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.20039126}
- {dist_correction: 1.060211473, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: 0.025999999, laser_id: 16, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: -0.02283403613875744, vert_correction: -0.044039090164117,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.20340445}
- {dist_correction: 1.4043311109999999, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0,
  focal_distance: 0, focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: -0.025999999, laser_id: 17,
  max_intensity: 255, min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: 0.016306609456053767, vert_correction: -0.03852929515508114,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.20380130000000002}
- {dist_correction: 1.2371826620000002, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0,
  focal_distance: 0, focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: 0.025999999, laser_id: 18,
  max_intensity: 255, min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: -0.03638080182719313, vert_correction: -0.08028060773568398,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.20078812}
- {dist_correction: 1.376363987, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: -0.025999999, laser_id: 19, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: 0.00298499996777161, vert_correction: -0.07418467880395085,

  vert_offset_correction: 0.20122907}
- {dist_correction: 1.106383391, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: 0.025999999, laser_id: 20, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: 0.05077396319105422, vert_correction: -0.032200364768206785,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.20425696}
- {dist_correction: 1.439996785, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: -0.025999999, laser_id: 21, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: 0.09039287787013092, vert_correction: -0.026481671300999723,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.20466851}
- {dist_correction: 1.160188217, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: 0.025999999, laser_id: 22, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: 0.03812992367965204, vert_correction: -0.0682866702093939,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.20165533}
- {dist_correction: 1.3670362800000002, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0,
  focal_distance: 0, focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: -0.025999999, laser_id: 23,
  max_intensity: 255, min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: 0.0765993714946823, vert_correction: -0.06238391431927152,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.20208158999999998}
- {dist_correction: 1.105859584, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: 0.025999999, laser_id: 24, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: -0.0976074110087475, vert_correction: 0.015211696348436898,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.20766700000000002}
- {dist_correction: 1.334790095, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: -0.025999999, laser_id: 25, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: -0.05862188504186577, vert_correction: 0.021342095532896902,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.20810794999999999}
- {dist_correction: 1.387242362, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: 0.025999999, laser_id: 26, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: -0.11097796127458481, vert_correction: -0.020352598566771237,

  vert_offset_correction: 0.20510947000000002}
- {dist_correction: 1.338619538, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: -0.025999999, laser_id: 27, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: -0.07188375714583993, vert_correction: -0.014835106655734082,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.20550633000000001}
- {dist_correction: 1.195386307, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: 0.025999999, laser_id: 28, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: -0.02322316776746509, vert_correction: 0.027266615678791652,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.20853421000000003}
- {dist_correction: 1.369630363, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: -0.025999999, laser_id: 29, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: 0.015424211128818232, vert_correction: 0.032780843824127576,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.20893107}
- {dist_correction: 1.318920053, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: 0.025999999, laser_id: 30, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: -0.03658813472502529, vert_correction: -0.008907898702791258,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.20593258}

- {dist_correction: 1.297194619, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: -0.025999999, laser_id: 31, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: 0.003096632972058419, vert_correction: -0.0027756669226166623,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.20637354}
- {dist_correction: 1.0381427650000001, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0,
  focal_distance: 0, focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: 0.025999999, laser_id: 32,
  max_intensity: 255, min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: -0.1480978384814982, vert_correction: -0.3964899891939334,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.10813505}
- {dist_correction: 0.933139253, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: -0.025999999, laser_id: 33, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: -0.08797836320298319, vert_correction: -0.3907365636746116,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.10855422}
- {dist_correction: 1.214292702, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: 0.025999999, laser_id: 34, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: 0.06686926912522753, vert_correction: -0.20165593518737052,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.12144683}
- {dist_correction: 0.857483745, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: -0.025999999, laser_id: 35, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: 0.12415029798793166, vert_correction: -0.19320431791092813,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.12199302}
- {dist_correction: 0.936412393, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: 0.025999999, laser_id: 36, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: -0.02883784135658254, vert_correction: -0.3821431034898597,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.10917662}
- {dist_correction: 0.88486166, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: -0.025999999, laser_id: 37, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: 0.03236450425771059, vert_correction: -0.37295815122160686,

  vert_offset_correction: 0.10983713}
- {dist_correction: 1.1186065790000002, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0,
  focal_distance: 0, focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: 0.025999999, laser_id: 38,
  max_intensity: 255, min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: -0.047917696963580454, vert_correction: -0.43598249665660516,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.10520087}
- {dist_correction: 0.876580252, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: -0.025999999, laser_id: 39, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: 0.010541523391999447, vert_correction: -0.4275517011581391,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.10583598000000001}
- {dist_correction: 0.980656935, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: 0.025999999, laser_id: 40, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: 0.09060940167180409, vert_correction: -0.3635281372730815,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.11051034}
- {dist_correction: 0.8760915640000001, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0,
  focal_distance: 0, focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: -0.025999999, laser_id: 41,
  max_intensity: 255, min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: 0.15200511231392566, vert_correction: -0.351509782590556,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.11136138000000001}
- {dist_correction: 1.072785023, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: 0.025999999, laser_id: 42, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: 0.07097199190861032, vert_correction: -0.4166650877757768,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.10664891000000001}

- {dist_correction: 0.820751296, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: -0.025999999, laser_id: 43, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: 0.13316200887463153, vert_correction: -0.40394547725309254,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.10758886000000001}
- {dist_correction: 1.077584616, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: 0.025999999, laser_id: 44, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: -0.14501539503625852, vert_correction: -0.2874187617299088,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.1157817}
- {dist_correction: 0.925046673, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: -0.025999999, laser_id: 45, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: -0.08578884940168556, vert_correction: -0.2819583420854119,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.11615006}
- {dist_correction: 1.233083807, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: 0.025999999, laser_id: 46, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: -0.16894748762061568, vert_correction: -0.3431963604842866,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.11194568}
- {dist_correction: 0.845306021, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: -0.025999999, laser_id: 47, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: -0.10868622004833936, vert_correction: -0.335197900494832,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.11250457000000001}
- {dist_correction: 1.107458999, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: 0.025999999, laser_id: 48, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: -0.02898399173748604, vert_correction: -0.2734510662591234,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.11672166}
- {dist_correction: 0.9165825340000001, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0,
  focal_distance: 0, focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: -0.025999999, laser_id: 49,
  max_intensity: 255, min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: 0.03068315877609437, vert_correction: -0.2652837631178309,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.11726784999999999}

- {dist_correction: 1.322560915, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: 0.025999999, laser_id: 50, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: -0.049409635824111744, vert_correction: -0.32807086594760565,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.11299994999999999}
- {dist_correction: 0.9346085960000001, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0,
  focal_distance: 0, focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: -0.025999999, laser_id: 51,
  max_intensity: 255, min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: 0.009888393260635137, vert_correction: -0.3196199817094491,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.11358424}
- {dist_correction: 1.0648798449999999, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0,
  focal_distance: 0, focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: 0.025999999, laser_id: 52,
  max_intensity: 255, min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: 0.0872253967477463, vert_correction: -0.25478428121685354,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.11796646000000001}
- {dist_correction: 0.9004575370000001, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0,
  focal_distance: 0, focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: -0.025999999, laser_id: 53,
  max_intensity: 255, min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: 0.1442667081283475, vert_correction: -0.24268675839945758,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.11876669}
- {dist_correction: 1.136431747, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: 0.025999999, laser_id: 54, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: 0.06716519842654943, vert_correction: -0.3103803482757313,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.11421935}
- {dist_correction: 0.942405998, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: -0.025999999, laser_id: 55, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: 0.12626596865390666, vert_correction: -0.30015317264465,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.11491796000000001}
- {dist_correction: 1.197193415, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: 0.025999999, laser_id: 56, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: -0.14275420056258145, vert_correction: -0.18294638957842674,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.12265353}
- {dist_correction: 1.015606208, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: -0.025999999, laser_id: 57, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: -0.08327387881878079, vert_correction: -0.17364113176483395,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.12325052}
- {dist_correction: 1.129644982, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: 0.025999999, laser_id: 58, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: -0.16462279909895197, vert_correction: -0.23400086557751998,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.11933828}
- {dist_correction: 0.950396769, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: -0.025999999, laser_id: 59, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: -0.10591289361224963, vert_correction: -0.22780218911272196,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.11974475}
- {dist_correction: 1.13498927, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: 0.025999999, laser_id: 60, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: -0.027951906992282463, vert_correction: -0.16669180664204566,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.1236951}
- {dist_correction: 0.9873951700000001, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0,
  focal_distance: 0, focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: -0.025999999, laser_id: 61,
  max_intensity: 255, min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: 0.02763049064789369, vert_correction: -0.15753373244427354,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.12427939}
- {dist_correction: 1.112591409, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: 0.025999999, laser_id: 62, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: -0.04956258775311027, vert_correction: -0.22002877187701952,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.12025283}
- {dist_correction: 0.951754713, dist_correction_x: 0, dist_correction_y: 0, focal_distance: 0,
  focal_slope: 0, horiz_offset_correction: -0.025999999, laser_id: 63, max_intensity: 255,
  min_intensity: 0, rot_correction: 0.008628967163054533, vert_correction: -0.21183750536509716,
  vert_offset_correction: 0.12078632000000002}
num_lasers: 64
```

I have attached resulting image from this launch file and calibration file. But point cloud projected on the rviz appears to be not aligned/projected properly.  Seems its because of calibration file. But i am not sure. Could any one please suggest me the possible solution.[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300230/velodyne-hdl--64e-s2-launch-file-configuration/) by [Ajay](https://answers.ros.org/users/35065/ajay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 63 on 2018-08-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2018-08-10**:
I dont think that the calibration file will give us much info in this case. What is the problem with the projection? As far as I can see it looks pretty good. Is it a scaling problem?

**Comment by [Ajay](https://answers.ros.org/users/35065/ajay/) on 2018-08-10**:
Hello Pavel, Again Thanks for your quick response. The problem with current projection is that, planar surface points also mapped in different depth values. Each channel data has varied depth values. PLease observe the wall points its not clear.

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2018-08-10**:
aha I see. Little variance in the channels is expected, but if it is greater than you are right to suspect the calibration

**Comment by [Ajay](https://answers.ros.org/users/35065/ajay/) on 2018-08-10**:
Even I have tried with different calibration file, which is I found online. But each calibration files has a different projection result. Few are very very bad, few are good. One that I posted is good one I found so far. So it made me clear that the issue is related to the calibration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a separate branch in the velodyne repo. It is supposed to contain fixes for the 32 LiDAR so you can give it a try.
Take a look at [maint/vlp_32c_support branch](https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne/tree/maint/vlp_32c_support).

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2018-08-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ajay](https://answers.ros.org/users/35065/ajay/) on 2018-08-10**:
Thank you Pavel, Finally, the problem got solved. I received a calibration file from the Velodyne technical support. Also, they mentioned that each unit of the Velodyne sensor comes with the separate calibration file. Thanks a lot for Velodyne Technical Support, for their quick and perfect response.